# Xiaomi Mi 10T Pro shows Samsung logo on boot

Tags: samsung, xiaomi, boot-animation

I just noticed that my Xiaomi Mi 10T Pro shows the Samsung logo while booting.

[image]

The phone also shows the Samsung logo in the About Phone section.

[image]

Does anyone have any clue why is this?

Comment: Are you sure the phone is genuine (may be the phone is forged and the original phone is a Samsung phone)? From the hardware specs of the Xiaomi mi 10T Pro I don't see a point why there should be any Samsung logo.

Comment: @Robert I've got the phone directly from slovak branch of https://www.telekom.com/en. Btw i also stumbled across this video on youtube /shorts/ft0YJpmYS80 but that's the only notice of something like this i've found on the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have installed the **[One UI 3.0](https://www.mtzfile.pw/detail/cc7ccf7b-5795-4267-8893-f765319897b0)** theme.

"Samsung" and the Samsung logo are part of its design because it tries to imitate the Samsung's UI.